# Oracle sql - can we have 2 unique column in the same table

Tags: sql, oracle, spring

In my web application, I have customer name and customer phone number. I should allow the same phone number multiple times. But I should not allow the same customer name to be entered multiple times. If there is already a customer named 'Sean Patrick' with mobile number '6039274849'. In future I should not allow a new user with same name ('Sean Patrick'). But I can allow the same mobile number to be entered ('6039274849').

Assume the table structure as

```
CUSTOMER TABLE

columns
CUSTOMER_ID UNIQUE
CUSTOMER NAME
CUST_MOB_NUMBER
```

I am using Spring ROO. We will use HibernateJPA(aspectJ code) for database related stuffs.

Can anyone tell how to do this. As of now I am thinking of making 2 columns uique.
Is there any any way to make 2 columns unique together?

Comment: If anything you should encounter a customer with multiple phone numbers, but you shouldn't really encounter multiple customers with the same phone number.

Comment: And you'll probably encounter customer's with the same name.

Comment: In other words, the mobile number may be anything(maynot be unique). But there should be unique customer name. No repetition of name. Similar to user_id in gmail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the requirements make sense (it really doesn't make sense to say that no two customers are going to have the same name-- there are lots of John Smiths in the world).  And people often have multiple mobile numbers.

You can declare both `customer_id` and `customer_name` as unique (though `customer_id` almost certainly ought to be declared as a primary key, not merely unique)

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_name    VARCHAR2(100) UNIQUE,
  cust_mob_number  VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

You an also declare a combination of two columns as unique

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  customer_id      NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_name    VARCHAR2(100),
  cust_mob_number  VARCHAR2(20),
  CONSTRAINT uk_name_and_number UNIQUE( customer_name, customer_mob_number )
);
```